org.xml.sax.SAXParseException for freemarker template in springboot
I am trying to generate document using freemarker in springboot.
Template has:
<tr>
        <td style="width: 100%"  align='center'>
            <div class="logo-container">
                <img class="company-logo" src="${companyLogo}" alt="LOGO" align='center'" />
            </div>
        </td>   
</tr>

value for 'companylogo' is:
..../image/tmpimages.png.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20240725T043642Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=360000&X-Amz-Credential=xxxxxxxxxxxx%wdddeddd%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=.....

This setup gives error as:
"Can't load the XML resource (using TrAX transformer). org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 87; columnNumber: 180; The reference to entity \"X-Amz-Date\" must end with the ';' delimiter."

What causes this? And what's the solution?

You need to URL encode the value for companyLogo before putting it in the model. This will turn & into &amp; or %26, which will then be converted back . The URL can only have safe characters and as & is the prefix for HTML entities, this is what freemarker tries to do determine the HTML entity for X-Amz-Date, which of course isn't an HTML entity. So URL encoding this before putting it into the model will solve this.

URL encoding is not what you want. The & character separates query parameters, while %26 will be interpreted as a literal & that's part of the previous query parameter value. So you change the meaning of the URL. It's HTML or XML escaping that's needed here, but see my answer.

Turn HTML/XML auto-escaping on! Generating HTML/XML without that is a security risk too. HTML auto-escaping will replace that & with &amp; in the output.
How to turn on auto-escaping? Using ftlh file extension instead of ftl is the easiest way (assuming you need HTML, though it seems you are generating XML here). If you can't do that, and you can't change the defaults in the FreeMarker configuration either, then start the template with<#ftl output_format="HTML"> (or I guess <#ftl output_format="XML"> in your case).
See also: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_quickstart_template.html#dgui_quickstart_template_autoescaping
